# Do you lose the reputation (points) you acquired from a question if/when it is deleted?

Tags: discussion, reputation, deleted-questions

Do you lose the reputation (points) you acquired from a question if/when it is deleted?

This could apply to reputation coming from votes on the question itself or rep from votes/acceptances/bounties on answers.

Comment: dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13661/cost-to-reputation-on-down-votes

Comment: Thanks for the dupe notice, but I don't think that question is an exact duplicate. I think it would be beneficial for others if I left the question on here unless another duplication is provided. Thanks again.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Although [Ian's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13763/162704) was true at the time, currently if a post is deleted you keep the reputation earned from it if the post was "worthwhile", [which is defined as:](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/)

> - A score of 3 or greater
> - Visible on the site for at least 60 days

If any of the above doesn't apply, the reputation is removed. Also [rep-recalculations aren't needed anymore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/recent-reputation-history-changes):

> Here’s what will be different:
>
> - Your reputation will be correct at all times
> - Deletions will have a much more immediate effect on reputation, not waiting on a recalc (but reputation sync takes up to 5 minutes on a delete/undelete action; as to not block the user's response thread, it's offloaded to a background queue)
> - Recalcs will no longer be necessary

Answer (score 6):

You keep them unless a rep-recalculation is performed on your account. This is a manual process and is used at the mod's discretion. If it is used, all reputation, gained or lost from questions and answers that no longer exist will be removed. The usual result will be a decrease in reputation, but it's not impossible for it to result in an increase.