# Do you no longer lose reputation from answers to questions that gets deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do you lose the points you acquired from a question if/when is deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13762/do-you-lose-the-points-you-acquired-from-a-question-if-when-is-deleted)

I saw [this comment](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4057/when-should-a-question-be-closed-but-not-deleted#comment11479_4060) recently:

> Quite recently SE yielded to a ton of complaints about lost
>   reputation, and now you don't lose reputation from deleted posts if
>   they survived for more than two months and have a total score of at
>   least +3.

Is this true?

And if so, is there a way to tell when questions I have high-scoring answers on get deleted?

(Personally I'd rather lose rep and be aware that the answer has been deleted and have a link to find it, instead of not losing rep and never knowing the answer is gone until I try and find it)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's true. The gory details are in [this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/).

There's no way to be notified of posts that are removed and fit this criteria at the moment far as I know, though they will show up in your Reputation tab if you have the "show removed posts" checkbox checked and look at the history for the day when the post was originally made.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize it went that far back and that explains why there's been a few times when I couldn't find an answer of mine. I usually find them by looking through my reputation page for deleted posts, but typically I only look through a few months and didn't think to look back as far back as the post's creation date and look for upvote rep for the question.

Comment: if i edit the deleted answer,and if it is moderator un-deleted my answer, will there be any change in reputation ?

Comment: @Lucifer No. At least not intentionally. If you were to gain rep when you didn't lose it in the first place, that'd be a bug.

Comment: My [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9172004/996493) went deleted ( because of there were only links, those days i was new to S.O. ), when this answer got undeleted, there was no change in my reputation. It has +3 votes and -2 = 26 rep.