# If someone deletes a question that I answered, do I lose the points?

Tags: support, reputation, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do you lose the points you acquired if a question is deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13762/do-you-lose-the-points-you-acquired-if-a-question-is-deleted)

I think this just happened to me, I lost 15 rep points and there's no record of it, if someone deletes the question with one of my accepted answers do I lose those points?

Comment: Yes, you will loose the points

Comment: Hmmm, I think that's hardly fair, considering people put effort and time into the answers, but thank you.

Comment: @8vius Nothing fair or unfair about it, if a post is removed the reputation doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Yes, it's a duplicate, I'll delete my question

Comment: Worth to mention that if your answer has more than two upvotes and is more than three months old, you will keep the reputation you gained for it.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd It's actually 3+ score (net score, regardless of upvotes/downvotes) and two months, check my answer on the duplicate.

Comment: @Yannis cheers! You're right as always. ;)